# Using DATA from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I know there are some similar questions but there some others things I need to do also.
Here is my database design :

**LINKS**

```
ID  Link
--  --------
 1  A Link
 2  B Link
 3  C Link
```

**LinkCollection**

```
LinkCollectionID  Link1  Link2  Link3
----------------  -----  -----  -----
               1      2      1      3
               2      3      2      2
               3      1      3      1
```

The query I would like to do in MYSQL is

1. `Select from LinkCollection-TABLE where LinkCollectionID = '2'`
2. THEN select from current ROW Link1 (which in this case has the value 3)

Then select from LINKS-TABLE where ID = 'Link1 value' ( which is 3)

Then from current row select Link

The final result from the query should be "C Link". If we change LinkCollectionID to 1 then the final result should be B Link

which I want to output in php somehow.

I tried to read my way to this using JOINS and other stuff but I just can't figure it out. Hope my example was clear enough.

Comment: Please use code style to write your codes in posts.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    select t2.Link1 , t1.Link from LinkCollection t2
    INNER JOIN  LINKS t1
    ON t2.link1 = t1.id
    WHERE LinkCollectionID = '2'
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eaaf6/1)

Comment: Hat off to you. Thank you very much for that nice solution.

Comment: @user2700729 make sure to accept answer as solved.to help others

Answer (score 0):

Following query will work assuming LinkCollection will always return one row

```
select L.Link from Link L where L.id = (select Lc.link1 from LinkCollection Lc where Lc.LinkCollectionID=2)
```

To be on the safe side you could add limit 1 in the sub-query

```
select L.Link from Link L where L.id = (select Lc.link1 from LinkCollection Lc where Lc.LinkCollectionID=2 limit 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the link field you are looking for :

```
SELECT l.Link 
FROM LinkCollection lc
INNER JOIN LINKS l ON lc.Link1 = l.ID
WHERE lc.LinkCollectionID = '2'
```

SQLFIDLE : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9e38/6/0

Comment: :) you give something new ? or just enjoy copying :).

Comment: @echo_Me It seems I stuck too much time in the edit :) ... BTW...OP only look for link as output :)